# how to set dynamic margin in a box

Tags: css

I have a problem with margin, I made a simple code to explain here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .parent {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .content {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: row nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .left {
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 200px;
        margin-right: 50px;
      }
      .right {
        border: 1px solid red;
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right">this is my text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I make width of screen smaller to about 297px I want to decrease margin pixel by pixel until 50px then make the text box smaller. I don't know how to make it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `flex-flow` instead of `flex-wrap` in the `.content` css?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something called responsive web design and it is achieved using `@media` queries. As a first step, add Viewport Meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Then, once your browser comes to `297px`, you have to reset the margins:

```css
  @media screen and (max-width: 297px) {
    .left {
      margin-right: 20px;
    }
  }
```

Here's the full code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <style>
      .parent {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      .content {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 100px;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: row nowrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
      }
      .left {
        border: 1px solid red;
        width: 200px;
        margin-right: 50px;
      }
      .right {
        border: 1px solid red;
        font-size: 20px;
        width: 200px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 297px) {
        .left {
          margin-right: 20px;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right">this is my text</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Demo: https://jsbin.com/kinojedanu/edit?html,output**

Comment: thank you .. but i don't want to decrease margin left instantly from 50px to 20 px ... I want to decrease it 1px and 1px from 50px to 0px !

Comment: @Amirmasud Use CSS transition.

Comment: @Amirmasud Let me write the code for you. You just need to add `transition: all 0.5s linear;` for the `.left` class. Can you check it here: **https://jsbin.com/cayelijaga/edit?html,output**